# Facebook Real-time Updates - get updates for friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

I am using the facebook real-time updates API to get updates for my users' friends. I wonder which fields of the users' friend the update-notifications include and which for which fields a subscription can be posted

Specifically I am requesting the following fields for my users' friends:

> 'bio', 'birthday', 'education', 'email', 'events', 'feed',
>   'first_name', 'gender', 'hometown', 'id', 'interested_in',
>   'languages', 'last_name', 'link', 'locale', 'location', 'middle_name',
>   'name', 'picture', 'quotes', 'relationship_status', 'religion',
>   'significant_other', 'username', 'website', 'work'

Comment: It’s not mentioned anywhere in the docs explicitly – but I’m pretty sure you get real-time updates notifications only for users that are users of your app, and not for their (non-app-user-)friends …

Comment: so I suppose, you only get updates for changes in the friends field of the user, which means if the user has added new friends or unfriended friends. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that’s the info the user->friends connection contains.

Comment: did you tried in C# Facebook SDK ?