# Facebook Graph API - Get updated friends ONLY

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

As described here ([Facebook Real-time Updates - get updates for friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144065/facebook-real-time-updates-get-updates-for-friends#comment16248262_12144065)) I am using the facebook real time API to get updates for users' friends. In the provided callback URL where facebook POSTs the updates to I get entries such as (replaced uid/id) :

```
        [ { uid: '123456',
            id: '123456',
            time: 1346075439,
            changed_fields: [ 'friends' ] },
          { uid: '654321',
            id: '654321',
            time: 1346075439,
            changed_fields: [ 'friends' ] }
        ]
```

I am now trying to the updated friends, however with the graph explorer tool I can't get the updated friends *only*. I tried to set the 'since' parameter as documented here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ -> Paging)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/123456/friends?since=1346075439
```

or also the 'time' parameter (not documented but I just tried it)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/123456/friends?time=1346075439
```

However, requests with either of the parameters still returns the *whole* friend list of the user

Is there any possibility how I can get only the updated friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the friends list is not sorted or queryable by time - if you need to detect new friends, you need to compare the list you receive from the API with the previous list you retrieved

Comment: Looks like it still works this way in 2019. This is not an optimized implementation by facebook as downloading hundreds of friends details all over again for minor or no change is very resource and cost consuming at scale.